# Creating "private" shared folder on the file server for each user on the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, file-server

We have a Windows Server 2008 File Server (Raid-5 NAS) where I'd like to setup a private folder for each user on the domain and provide each with a soft quota of about 2 GB.  The quota part is no problem, but is there a way of creating the folders and assigning the respective permissions without actually having to go to the shared folder on the NAS and creating each sub-folder by hand?

It would also be very nice if there is an automatic way to mount each share folder as a drive for each user.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the users profile in ADUC, you will see that there is a field called "Home Folder". You can use the "Connect to" option to map a drive to the share on the file and print server eg \\fileserver\users\%UserName%

On the fileserver, create a folder called users and share it. Change the permissions as follows:

1) Turn off inheritance on the folder and copy the permissions. You do this by:

a. Click the Advanced button found on the Security tab.

b. Clear Allow inheritable permissions to propagate to this object check box in the Advanced Security Settings dialog box.

c. Click Copy when prompted by the Security dialog box.

2) Click OK to return to the Security tab. Ensure we have the following permissions set:

Administrators: Full Control

System: Full Control

Creator Owner: Full Control

Authenticated Users: Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read

3) Change permissions for Authenticated Users so they cannot access other users’ folders. You do this by:

a. Click Advanced on the Security tab.

b. Click Authenticated Users, and then click Edit.

c. On the Permissions Entry for users dialog box, drop down the Apply onto and select This folder only.

d. Click OK twice.

You can find the original article for Windows 2003 (Should work in 2008) [here](http://blogs.technet.com/askds/archive/2008/06/30/automatic-creation-of-user-folders-for-home-roaming-profile-and-redirected-folders.aspx)

Comment: IIRC, when you enter the path for the AD user's home directory, you'll get a prompt asking if you want AD to create the directory and assign the proper permissions.  It's fairly automatic once the setup described above is complete.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't comment earlier, but I have to thank you, this worked like a charm. Many, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to AD UC and highlight all the users you would like to create a
  home folder for.
- Group them in one group (Domain Users) then highlight them again Then
  right click and go to properties.
- Go to profile tab and mark on home folder and set the root path to
  the server e.g. \\fileserver\users\%UserName% and then click apply.
- You will probably see all the user's usernames folders in C:/users/..
- Then go to users folder in c drive and right click on it then go to
  security tab and go to advanced and disable inheritance of any user
  and apply the settings.
- Go back and set full access permission to Domain Users and
  Administrators.
- Thereafter you can see the Z drive automatically mapped to any user
  on any client computer they logging to.